# animate label text color from transparent to black in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, label, scene2d

I have been trying to animate the color of label from transparent to black. I had little success. The label remains fully transparent during whole aniamtion. This is the code I used. Stage is already set correctly since other Actor work normally.

```
            Label.LabelStyle lsBy = new Label.LabelStyle(byFont, new Color(0,0,0,0));

            Label byLabel = new Label("text to animate",lsBy);
            ColorAction ca= new ColorAction();
            ca.setEndColor(new Color(0,0,0,1));
            ca.setDuration(0.8f);
            label.addAction(ca);
```

What is the correct way to animate label text color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit confusing, but a Label has two colors. One is the color of the font in its LabelStyle. The other is its own color, as all Actors have. These two colors are multiplied by each other for drawing. ColorAction only affects the color of the actor, not the color of the style.

You need to leave the label style's color as white, and set the color of the Label actor itself to transparent.

```
        Label.LabelStyle lsBy = new Label.LabelStyle(byFont, Color.WHITE);

        Label byLabel = new Label("text to animate",lsBy);
        byLabel.setColor(Color.CLEAR);
        ColorAction ca= new ColorAction();
        ca.setEndColor(new Color(0,0,0,1));
        ca.setDuration(0.8f);
        label.addAction(ca);
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you!